# String doesn't contain character even after checking with if-statement

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I am trying to read sensor data into Unity. For that I am using a TCP Server on a ESP32 by sending the data in json. 
I am now trying to parse the received data into a serializable object.
Currently I am reading data from the server until I receive the final "}" bracket as a very rudimentary check for valid json as a starting point.

Now this is where I can't find my error. I am starting a Thread in the class which runs in the background and is constantly reading the server for new values.
But somehow I can't successfully concatenate the string which should be checked for the "}" character.

My code so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

[Serializable]
public class SensorData
{
    public int capacity;
}

public class MugSensorRead : MonoBehaviour 
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    const string IP = "192.168.137.50";
    const int PORT = 5000;

    public SensorData sensorData;
    public int capacity;

    bool _threadRunning;
    Thread _thread;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        client.Connect (IP, PORT);  
        _thread = new Thread (updateSensorData);
        _thread.Start ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        capacity = sensorData.capacity;
    }

    void updateSensorData()
    {
        _threadRunning = true;

        while (_threadRunning) 
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream ();
            string jsonMsg = "";
            bool validJson = false;

            while (!validJson) 
            {
                byte[] inStream = new byte[1024];
                stream.Read (inStream, 0, 1024);
                string jsonData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (inStream);
                jsonMsg = string.Concat (jsonMsg, jsonData);
                if (jsonMsg.Contains("}"))
                {
                    validJson = true;
                    //This part here is executed, but when I print(jsonMsg), it just prints the character "{" which gets transmitted in the first segment
                }
            }
            sensorData = JsonUtility.FromJson<SensorData> (jsonMsg);
        }
        _threadRunning = false;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        if (_threadRunning) 
        {
            _threadRunning = false;
            _thread.Join ();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you spot my error? I'm just not able to see, where my code fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that you are not checking how many bytes the read returned and you are adding 0's as part of the string content.

This should be replaced:

```
    while (!validJson) 
    {
        byte[] inStream = new byte[1024];
        stream.Read (inStream, 0, 1024);
        string jsonData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (inStream);
        jsonMsg = string.Concat (jsonMsg, jsonData);
        if (jsonMsg.Contains("}"))
        {
            validJson = true;
            //This part here is executed, but when I print(jsonMsg), it just prints the character "{" which gets transmitted in the first segment
        }
    }
```

This would be the correct code:

```
    while (!validJson) 
    {
        byte[] inStream = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = stream.Read (inStream, 0, 1024);
        string jsonData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (inStream, 0, bytesRead);
        jsonMsg = string.Concat (jsonMsg, jsonData);
        if (jsonMsg.Contains("}"))
        {
            validJson = true;
            //This part here is executed, but when I print(jsonMsg), it just prints the character "{" which gets transmitted in the first segment
        }
    }
```

0's in the array get converted to string end bytes that's why you don't see the '}' char, because there are string end characters before.